# Why IONIC push notification looks like Javascript alert?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I am successfully able to send push notifications using IONIC Framework. But these notifications doesn't looks like I receive other android notifications, rather it these looks like normal Javascript alert.

Is there any setting to set push notification type like (alert or something else) ?

I go through the following link : https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/

If someone has faced and resolved this, then please comment.

1. First screenshot shows push notification as Javascript alert.
2. Second screenshot shows default Android notification after locking phone's screen.
3. Third screenshot shows default Android notification after unlocking screen

[image: Alert type notification]

[image: Default Android notification on lock screen]

[image: Default Android notification after unlocking screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by applying below code to $ionicPlatform.ready in my app.js file which shows notifications with onNotification event, if onNotification is not present then IONIC show default Javascript alert.

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
    onNotification:  function(notification) {
            var payload = notification.payload;
            console.log(notification, payload);
          },
    pluginConfig: {
      ios: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },
      android: {
        sound: true,
        vibrate: true,
        forceShow: true,
        iconColor: "#601dc2"
      },
    }
  });
```

Comment: Great!!! Can you please share screenshot here in this answer so I can understand the default view of notification.

Comment: Hi Kiran, please check, I have edited question and added default view of android notification after applying above code.

Comment: Vinod- Please follow https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/ this link and check if your code configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

While working with push notification you have **Two possibilities** to get notification **One** in the notification tray on the head of screen while your app is in background mode and **Second** when you are working with your app in foreground mode

First one is display like other notifications to notify that you got a notification for your app with message and logo whatever you set

But for other notification it is just use to get the data and message whatever you passed through it, and now its on you that how you want to show it in the application

*Either you can set a div and hide show it when notification display with the design and position as you like or as per your app theme*

```
<script>
function devicePushNotification(data) 
{
    if (data.additionalData.foreground == true)
    {
        $("#setNotificationText").text(data.message);
        $("#setNotificationText").css("display","block");

    }
}
</script>
<div style="width:50%;margin: 0 auto;display:none" id="setNotificationText">
</div>
```

*Or you can just alert the message that you got a notification for anything you have passed like,*

```
<script>
function devicePushNotification(data) 
{
    if (data.additionalData.foreground == true)
    {
        alert(data.message);
    }
}
</script>
```

**So, if you get the notification successfully, then you just have to create any well formed container to display it.**

*Hope this helps you*